# After updating aws-amplify i am getting error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

after updating aws-amplify, i am getting this error, i am using amplify storage

**Refused to set unsafe header "host"
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at AWSS3Provider. (AWSS3Provider.ts:409)**

am i missing something ? need help!

Answer (score 0):

When I use aws-amplify@3.0.7 and aws-amplify-react@4.1.6 I had the same error, after I switched to "aws-amplify": "^2.3.0" and "aws-amplify-react": "^3.1.9", the issue gone

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering in AWS Amplify seems to be related to the setting of unsafe headers and an issue within the AWSS3Provider. This could be due to outdated dependencies, misconfiguration, or some other internal bug.
Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and fix the issue:

Update AWS Amplify and its dependencies. Make sure you have the latest version of AWS Amplify and its related libraries. You can do this by running the following command in your project directory:
`npm update aws-amplify @aws-amplify/api @aws-amplify/pubsub`

Double-check your `aws-exports.js` (or `aws-exports.ts`) file to ensure all the configurations are correct. This file contains your AWS Amplify project settings, including the API endpoint and other configurations required for the AWS services you're using. Look for any potential issues like missing or incorrect values.

You need to verify AWS S3 settings. If you are using the AWS S3 storage service with Amplify, verify the settings for the storage configuration in `aws-exports.js`. Ensure that the bucket name, region, and other settings are correct.

Review the code where you're using AWS Amplify and ensure there are no syntax errors or incorrect method calls that could be causing the problem.

Sometimes, caching issues in the browser can cause strange errors. Clear your browser's cache and try again to see if the issue persists.

Also, Amplify provides logging features that can help you debug issues. You can enable logging by adding the following line in your app's entry point (e.g., `index.js` or `App.js`):
`js Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG';` 
With logging enabled, check the console output for any additional error messages or warnings that could shed light on the problem.

Check for conflicting libraries. Ensure that there are no conflicts between the versions of libraries used in your project. Conflicts can cause unexpected behavior and errors.

Remember that the error message you provided might not be the root cause of the problem, but rather a symptom of a more significant issue. Follow the steps above to isolate and resolve the problem, and consider reaching out to the AWS Amplify community or support channels for further assistance.